# How to lower font size to fit new user digits in div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

is there a way to lower the fontsize of `digit` when a user adds more numbers so that it can it fit in the `box` div?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [digit, setDigit] = useState(32);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box">{digit}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={digit}
        onChange={(e) => setDigit(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: green;
  height:100%;
  padding:20px;
}

.box{
  width:50%;
  height:35px;
  background:yellow;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? People don't have perfect vision, making the font size smaller just to fit the content on the screen suggests that you don't actually know what goes in this field: find out, or decide, what that field is _really_ for, and then limit its input based on what should go in it, and size it appropriately for that input, flagging it as invalid if people go over the limit?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly don't recommend doing this, but just for the information, this is the equation to make a fluid font size, maybe you can use it:

```
.box {
    font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
    }
```

The problem with this equation as I experienced before, is that it does not calculate automatically (I don't know why) so you need to update it every time  the user type a new digit.